# ¿Como hacer que mi web PHP acepte el SSL instalado?

Tags: php, html, prestashop, ssl

Tengo el problema elabore una subpagina o micropagina web PHP la cual se sitúa en un subdirectorio dentro del servidor para una web hecha en Prestashop, no es un subdominio está habita dentro del mismo pero es extra a la web porque no se puede apreciar directamente en la tienda. Por ejemplo es algo así `www.tienda.com/procesador_de_pagos`, pero el problema es que no acepta el certificado SSl y el navegador me indica que está web es insegura teniendo instalado el certificado en el servidor.

Disculpen mi ignorancia pero no encuentro la forma correcta de trabajar dicho problema porque aunque pienso que debería reinstalar el certificado pero no me arriesgo.

Muchas gracias espero sus comentarios y apoyo.

Comment: Edita tu pregunta y añade más detalles. Cómo está configurado el certificado en tu sitio web? Cómo está configurada la subpágina? Para qué dominio está creado el certificado y cuál es la URL de la subpágina?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Necesitarás otro certificado SSL si o si, los certificados SSL son hechos para un dominio en específico, por lo que entiendo, ahora aparte de tu dominio estás trabajando con un subdominio en tu página, por ende, lo que tendrás que hacer es conseguir otro certificado SSL para tu subdominio. Y si estás trabajando con más de un subodminio, tendrás que hacerlo para cada subdominio que incorpores.

Dependiendo de donde estás alojando tu web, el servicio de hosting puede o no brindarte herramientas para que el proceso de certificados en subdominios sea más fácil.
Igual recuerda siempre tener instalado el certificado SSL antes de forzar el uso del mismo, porque de lo contrario la página puede que ni cargue.

En prestashop lo configuras todo desde las preferencias -> configuración

Igualmente si pudieras dar más información de quién administra los certificados SSL se podría dar una respuesta más detallada.
Pero por ahora lo que deberías saber es que el certificado SSL se crea sobre un dominio en especifico, así que si montas un subdominio aunque la carpeta está ubicada dentro del dominio principal, necesitarás otro certificado si o si.

En godaddy por ejemplo tienes la opción de certificados Wildcard, que son los que te cubren todos los subdominios que quieras incluir también, creando el SSL para

```
*.tudominio.com
De esa manera si tu web es:
"tudominio.com" también cubriría
"sub.tudominio.com"
"otro.tudominio.com"
"cualquier.tudominio.com", etc.
```

Comment: Discúlpeme amigo pero también afecta si la ruta es la siguiente dominio/procesador_de_pagos así está ordenado y todo dentro de la public_html en el dominio principal? Porque donde tengo entendido este debería de responder al certificado del dominio ya que esta dentro de este por decirte este ejemplo: www.tienda.com/procesador_de_pagos

Comment: Entonces es simplemente una página creada dentro de la misma web,si no te toma el certificado es porque lo tienes mal configurado o porque no lo haz activado una vez instalado en el servidor.
En Prestashop como dije arriba, luego de instalarlo, anda a Preferencias, después en el apartado de Configuración te saldrá una opción que dice "Por favor, haga click aquí para comprobar si su tienda soporta HTTPS", ahí si está todo bien de dará la opción de dar SI en el campo de Activar SSL en todas las páginas. Guardas cambios y listo,recuerda borrar caché para que no tengas problemas con el navegador

Comment: Amigo hice todo lo que me explico y sigue ocurriendo lo mismo. No será que el certificado de Prestashop solo se instala en lo que respecta Prestashop y lo demás quedara sin este ?

Comment: Revisa si está forzando de verdad del https en esa página o no. Prueba ingresando directamente a`https://www.tienda.com/procesador_de_pagos`